# Logging the request information with each request in winston

Tags: node.js, express, logging, npm, winston

I have extended [winston-express-request-logger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston-express-request-logger) to print out every request, process, error, and user information  in my Express/NodeJs application.

But the application actually logs no information regarding the request.

Sample log output:

```
2018-02-22T11:18:44.871Z - info: root access
```

I thought the official tutorial ([found here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston-express-request-logger)) would lead me to a working implementation.  Am I missing anything from the tutorials?

**The whole application code:**

```js
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const winston = require('winston');

var winstonExRegLogger = require("winston-express-request-logger");
winstonExRegLogger.createLogger({
    transports: [
      
         new (winston.transports.Console)({
            handleExceptions: true,
            timestamp: true,
            level:"info"
        })
    ],

    exitOnError: false
});

function configureApp(app, env) {
    app.use(winstonExRegLogger.requestDetails);
}

app.use(winstonExRegLogger.requestDetails);


var logger = require("winston-express-request-logger").getLogger();

logger.error('testing error log');
logger.info('testing info log');


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  logger.info('root access');
  res.status(200).send('hello world!');
});


app.get('/home', (req, res) => {
  logger.info('home');
  res.status(200).send('okay');
});

app.post('/p', (req, res) => {
  logger.info('post ni');
  logger.error('in post');
  res.status(200).send('post acknowledged');
});

if (module === require.main) {
  const server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8081, () => {
  const port = server.address().port;
  console.log(`App listening on port ${port}`);
  });
}

module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to pass the req object to the logger.info calls, e.g. do

```
logger.info(req, 'home');
```

instead of

```
logger.info('home');
```

This will give a log line like:

```
2018-02-22T14:28:21.481Z - info: pId: 25868 - uId: cjdylrofa0000yktbj5rkrtsr - cId: anonymous - cIP: ::1 - cAction: GET /home home
2018-02-22T14:31:56.014Z - info: pId: 33536 - uId: cjdylw9yj0000vktbbqfeubz7 - cId: anonymous - cIP: ::1 - cAction: GET / root access
```

Which is probably what you want!

Comment: Also @Terry, is there a way to automatically make a log entry every time a GET or POST request is made and add this 'req' data automatically to each log entry without manually having to add it like this at every place where we want the log ?

Comment: Yes, there is, the express-winston module will do it. I've used that one as well. It will log various details of get/ post requests without needing to call for each request. You can colourize too!